# How to remove a single DataLabel from a Chart made with EPPlus and C#

Tags: c#, epplus

[image]Is it possible in any way to remove a single DataLabel from a Chart made with EPPlus and C#?

I just want to remove a single one, not the setting for the hole Chart...
How can the collection of DataLabels be accessed (dLbls > dLbl)?

```
var chart = (ExcelBarChart)worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("Chart", eChartType.ColumnStacked);
```

Also made use of coloring a individual point of Chart with this:
[Legend color is incorrect in excel chart created using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520427/legend-color-is-incorrect-in-excel-chart-created-using-epplus/36532733#36532733)

*(The red point at the upper right)*

Now I want to remove a specific label of a point, with generally applied DataLabels...

```
chart.DataLabel.ShowValue = true;
```

Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution. This Extension method is doing the trick...

```
public static void RemoveDataLabel(this ExcelBarChart chart, int serieNumber, int objectNumber)
{
    var chartXml = chart.ChartXml;

    var nsa = chart.WorkSheet.Drawings.NameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("a");
    var nsuri = chartXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;

    var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(chartXml.NameTable);
    nsm.AddNamespace("a", nsa);
    nsm.AddNamespace("c", nsuri);

    var dLbls = chart.ChartXml.SelectSingleNode(@"c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:barChart/c:ser[c:idx[@val='" + serieNumber + "']]/c:dLbls", nsm);

    var dLbl = chartXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "dLbl", nsuri);

    var idx = chartXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "idx", nsuri);
    var valueIdx = chartXml.CreateAttribute("val", nsuri);
    valueIdx.Value = objectNumber.ToString();
    idx.Attributes.Append(valueIdx);
    dLbl.AppendChild(idx);

    var delete = chartXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "delete", nsuri);
    var valueDelete = chartXml.CreateAttribute("val", nsuri);
    valueDelete.Value = "1";
    delete.Attributes.Append(valueDelete);
    dLbl.AppendChild(delete);

    dLbls.AppendChild(dLbl);
}
```